# Wrong pipeline triggered via AWS webhook

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, github-webhook

1. I have specified the **head reference as master**, my event type is **PUSH** but due to some unknown reason, when code was pushed in stage branch, master pipeline got triggered and stage code is deployed to master.
   May I know the reason for it?
2. If I select event type **PULL_REQUEST_MERGED**, **base refernece is master**, Pipeline should trigger on master instead of that branch on which PR is raised.

I have a long running branch master, and a short live hotfix_branch. My hotfix_bracnh didn't have the latest pull of master and its build spec file is old. I raised a PR, merged that in master. According to my understanding, build should run on master branch but it ran on hotfix_branch with old buildspec file.

Comment: Can you share your workflow files?

Comment: Can you specify which file?

Comment: Let me rephrase that: please share enough information, including relevant code/workflow files, so that someone reading this question can actually figure out what's wrong and answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask